# What are the prerequisite before applying new branding to existing branding site

Tags: branding, prerequisites

I have SharePoint site.
I have applied branding for SharePoint site.

Now I'm trying to applying new branding for same site.
So what are the point to take in consideration before applying new branding.

What are the prerequisite before applying new branding to existing branding site.

Means like anythings get conflicts (override) like site columns, content types and master page.

Considering if we were to deploy the new branding solution on this site and not messing with the existing data that should be still usable in new branding libraries, lists, etc. 
What would be the complications, what would be the measures for these complications and estimate for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Before you branding site you must have

1. Design html page with related css, js, etc. for branding master page
2. put your all stuffs in catalog folder
3. Activate site collection feature **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**
4. Activate web feature **SharePoint Server Publishing** from the site which you want to brand.
5. Now open your site in browser then goto **Design Manager** from site setting
   [image]

   6. In Design manager convert your html page to master page, once conversation successfull you can apply it into your site.

**Design Manager is a great feature for branding sharepoint sites**

For existing branding sites, Edit your html master page and publish as a major version so it automatically reflect to actual master page.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Practice to brand a SharePoint site**

1) create a Branding solution for SharePoint site. This feature will save our time and effort. This will be more reusable, scalable and flexible. With the use of this pattern for Branding, it will be easy for us to track the issues and also reduce our manual effort for deploying Branding in different-2 sites or web application

Below are the benefit that we can achieve through this feature:

**On Feature Activation:**

1.MasterPage: Deploy all master page into /_catalogs/masterpage/MasterPages/

2.PageLayouts: Deploy all PageLayouts pages into /_catalogs/masterpage/PageLayouts/

3.PublishingImages:deploy all images into /PublishingImages/Ravishankar.Images/

4.StyleLibrary:Deploy all styles and JavaScript file into Style library under folder Ravishankar.Js(for JavaScript) and Ravishankar.Styles(for all css)

5. set Master page default on activation.

**On Feature Deactivation:**

This feature will remove all customs files from the SharePoint site and revert all the changes to previous default settings.

**Do:**

1.Create master pages either through SharePoint designer or visual studio and put the pages into Branding solution under MasterPage Module

2.Create PageLayouts either through SharePoint designer or visual studio and put the pages into Branding solution under PageLayouts Module

3.Create Styles and JavaScript either through SharePoint designer or visual studio and put the pages Branding solution under StyleLibrary Module

4.Put all images into PublishingImages module in Branding Solution

**Don’t:**

1.Uploading master pages and PageLayouts manually

2.Upload images/stylesheets/JavaScript in any other location.

3.Declare/define JavaScript or styles directly on pages.

It will be really usual for multiple deployments.

Reference [https://sharepointbranding.codeplex.com/downloads/get/320661]